# Using a method in Java 8, how do I write an array to a file after first checking if it already exists?

Tags: java-8, ioexception, printwriter

The idea is to create an array of 10 elements & populate it with random numbers. Then, get an output file name from the user, and print my name followed by the array's contents to this new file. If the user chooses an existing filename, the program needs to let them know so and not overwrite that file.

```
private static void arrayOfTen() throws IOException {
    String userFilename;
    int[] randomList = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < randomList.length; i++) {
        randomList[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }
    System.out.println("An array of ten elements has been populated with" +
            "random integers. Please name a new file in which to print " +
            "this array: ");
    userFilename = input.nextLine();
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(userFilename);

    // Check to see if filename already in use & exit if so
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        // Create output file
        java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

        // Write formatted output to file
        outfile.print("Name");
        for (int i = 0; i < randomList.length; i++) {
            outfile.println(randomList[i]);
        }
        outfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what your actual problem is but since you asked for Java 8, let’s discuss things you can and should do better:

```
private static void arrayOfTen() throws IOException {
    int[] randomList = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(10, 0, 10).toArray();
    System.out.println("An array of ten elements has been populated with" +
            "random integers. Please name a new file in which to print " +
            "this array: ");
    String userFilename = input.nextLine();
    // Create output file, demand creating a new file
    try(BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(
            Paths.get(userFilename), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
        // Write formatted output to file
        w.write("Name");
        for(int value: randomList) {
            w.write(String.valueOf(value));
            w.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The most important thing is the `try(…)` construct to ensure proper closing of the file, which is not new to Java 8, but a Java 7 feature. Then, by creating a writer using `StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW` you ensure that the output channel will only be opened if the file is new, i.e. does not exist. Attempts to open an existing file will result in a `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`; this saves you from doing manual checks before opening. Note further that you can process all items of an array using the for-each syntax `for(int value: array)` (since Java 5).

Regarding specific Java 8 features, you can generate the desired array using the one liner `ThreadLocalRandom.current() .ints(10, 0, 10).toArray()`, but actually, there is no need to generate an array at all, as you could ask for a new random value right before writing it:

```
private static void arrayOfTen() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please name a new file in which to print ten random integers: ");
    String userFilename = input.nextLine();
    // Create output file, demand creating a new file
    try(BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(
            Paths.get(userFilename), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
        // Write formatted output to file
        w.write("Name");
        ThreadLocalRandom r=ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            w.write(String.valueOf(r.nextInt(10)));
            w.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that both examples replicate your original code’s behavior of writing `"Name"` at the beginning of the file (without a line terminator). I have no idea of the purpose of this, though…